# K8s nginx ingress: request blocked by CORS policy

Tags: kubernetes, cors, nginx-ingress

Try to solve puzzle related to my application.

I am trying to move old PHP application into K8s. In my example I will have 2 pods:

1. php app + Apache (apache is main process)
2. nodejs app

When I am trying to access to my PHP app I am getting this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.mydomain.com/api/...' from origin 'https://main.mydomain.com,' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I found some information about CORS and I added these config to my K8s NGINX ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ...
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "*.mydomain.com"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, accept"
```

I have two separate Ingress configurations, for API and PHP. I added above configuration for both ingress but still save this error.

Can it be related to Apache? Should I also add same CORS config into Apache config? But what about nodejs app? Both app are very old and I hoped that NGINX ingress will be enough but for now I am not sure where I need to find root cases of issue.

Comment: If possible can you update the question with your deployment manifests.

Comment: The value specified in `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin` is incorrect: it's missing `https://`. It should be `"https://*.mydomain.com"`. See https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#enable-cors.

Comment: Yeah, looks like `https` is helped and solved issue! thank you!